# MySQL: Extract regexp value from query

Tags: mysql

I would need to get value from given regexp.

For example:

```
> :"postalCode";s:4:"3150";
```

Is there any way I can extract 3150, from this part of column value. Column value stored serialized objects, so postalCode variable can be null type, that way I should check if positive integer follows **;s:POSITIVE_INT:"postalCodeValue**

Comment: What sort of data is this?  I was almost tempted to say JSON, but not quite.

Comment: it's PHP serialized data @TimBiegeleisen http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '"', -2), 1,
              INSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '"', -2), '"') - 1) AS num
FROM yourTable;
```

This query will extract the last quoted number in your string.

### Demo

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that this is only part of huge value that is stored in column type so it is in the middle of value this part. It has some random value before and after it (`:"postalCode";s:4:"3150";` is not full string on which I call these procedures), and I should point on it and fetch value.

Comment: Does `s:4:` always separate the postal code from the number?

Comment: Not, 4 is length of postalCode which is after that inside quotes. It can have different values. But `";s:11:"countryName` always comes after postalCode value which I need.

Answer (score 0):

avoiding regexp you could use  some string function eg:

```
SELECT LENGTH(':"postalCode";s:4:"3150"') - LOCATE(':', REVERSE(':"postalCode";s:4:"3150"'))+1
from dual ;
```

or

```
SELECT LENGTH(col_name) - LOCATE(':', REVERSE(col_name))+1
from my_table ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It also work with 2 times **SUBSTRING_INDEX**

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUBSTRING_INDEX( ':"postalCode";s:4:"3150";', '"',-2) , '"', 1);
```